# REST API authentication - Will this be sufficient?

Tags: api, rest, authentication

I have been trying to wrap my brain around authentication on a `REST API`.

I've tried to think of a way to successfully authenticate users, keeping in mind that users can access all data on the client, and I've come up with this idea.

```
Client sends username and password to the server
Server checks if they match a user.
    If it does, we create a hashed string with user_id+e-mail+currentTime+salt
    and stores this in a database-table with an expiration date.
Server returns hashed string to client

Client sends random request to server including key
Server checks if key is correct and if it's expired
```

Is this a proper way to do it, and do you see any security flaws?

Comment: You could also use a random UUID instead of the hashed string, maybe safer in case the salt is predictable, then valid hashes could be generated knowing the other parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're effectively storing session state on the server, which is something you shouldn't be doing on a RESTful API.

Authentication on a RESTful API should simply follow whatever is the standardized authentication method for the underlying protocol. Instead of reinventing HTTP authentication, you should simply require clients to authenticate through HTTP Basic Auth on every request, using the `Authorization` header. Obviously, all your client-server interactions should be done over SSL.

If you really need some authentication token with an expire date, you can have a resource that provides it once the client is authenticated with basic (like a signed timestamp) but clients should still send that in the `Authorization` header, with a custom realm, and no state should be stored on the server.